# AppEngine JDO Query filter "property has ancestor"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have an entity of kind 'ContainableObject' stored which has an entity of kind 'Container' as one of its properties.

```
class ContainableObject {

    @Persistent
    @Unowned
    private Container container;
    ...
```

The 'Container' has a parent Entity of kind 'Building'

Since the table is actually storing a Key to Container which contains its parent Key (i.e. the property container is `Key('Building',1,'Container',23)` is there any way to write a query along the lines of `select * from ContainableObject where container has ancestor Key('Building', 1)`

I know I could additionally store the Building as a direct property of the ContainableObject in order to use it in a query filter, but is this the only way? I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I would like some confirmation, since it's not quite a join as the parent key is buried in there somewhere.

Note: the ContainableObject is in a different entity group to Container, this is not an ancestor query, which the AppEngine implementation of JDO doesn't support anyway AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have the query you specified. You need to modify your code structure in order to achieve your goal.

Hope this helps.